# DataGridView и DataSet. Баг C# или так и должно быть?

Tags: c#, winforms, база-данных, ado.net

Например, есть форма с элементом `DataGridView dataGridView1`. Имеется файл ds.xml с данными датасета `'DSMain'` с одной таблицей `'DTMain'` с несколькими столбцами, строки в таблице `'DTMain'` еще не заполнены. Далее:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("DSMain");  
ds.ReadXml("ds.xml");  
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["DTMain"];
```

Также есть метод для сохранения `ds`, например, при выборе пункта меню 'Сохранить':

```
void SaveDataSet()  
{ ds.WriteXml("ds.xml",XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema); }
```

Запускаю программу, и бьюсь с такой проблемой. Если внести значение в ячейку новой (последней) строки датагрида и нажать кнопку-стрелку 'Вправо', а затем выбрать 'Сохранить', то никаких изменений во всей строке не сохранится, то есть она останется пустой. А если хотя бы раз нажать 'Enter' на строке датагрида, то при изменении остальных ячеек в этой строке, все изменения будут сохраняться. Пользуюсь студией 2010 C# Express. Кто что думает об этом? Это баг или у меня кривые руки? И как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Что происходит при нажатии кнопки-стрелки "Вправо"? Какая ячейка становиться активной?

Comment: Ну естественно, следующая вправо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подозреваю, что так и должно быть, это вроде как в MS Access сделано: если вы нажимаете вправо, то вы остаётесь в той же строке и, как бы считается, что вы всё ещё редактируете запись. Дело в том, что это не просто таблица, а редактор записей. Мне даже кажется, что сталкивался с чем-то подобным очень очень давно, когда ещё был .NET 1.0. Просто надо перед сохранением как-то закончить редактирование. Я не спец по .NET, но уверен, что такой метод должен быть. Что-нибудь вроде EndEdit или ApplyЧтоТо, AcceptChanges или что-то в этом духе. Посмотрите также на состояние самого DataSet. Возможно надо его пнуть, чтобы он счёл нужным принять изменения.

Возможно они:

[DataSet.AcceptChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.dataset.acceptchanges.aspx)

[DataGridView.EndEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms158620.aspx)

Comment: Я тоже думаю, что это вполне ожидаемое действие.

Comment: Перепробовал вроде все, не получается. Если у кого то получится решить эту проблему, огромная просьба отписаться

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, дело не в `DataSet`, а в гриде. Для диагностики ситуации попробуйте подписаться на `DataTable.TableNewRow` и посмотрите, вызывается ли обработчик при (или до) нажатии кнопки "Вправо" или нет. Если не вызывается - точно проблема в гриде. В этом случае нужно в обработчике "Сохранить" что-нибудь вызвать у грида, чтобы он применил к источнику данных изменения, внесённые пользователем.

Иначе, попробуйте `DataRow.EndEdit()`.